# sql code for activity completion in moodle

Tags: sql, moodle

can u give some sql code for knowing the activity completion status in moodle

iam fresher to moodle so i have no idea. but i found mdl_course_modules_completion table would be used

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct table for activity completion - `mdl_course_modules_completion`

Here is some SQL to get you going

The names in CAPITALS are the PHP constants, found in `/lib/completionlib.php`

You might want to expand the SQL to exclude deleted / suspended users and unenrolled users

```
SELECT u.id AS userid, u.firstname, u.lastname,
    c.id AS courseid, c.fullname AS coursename,
    cmc.coursemoduleid, m.name AS moduletype,
    CASE
        WHEN cm.completion = 0 THEN 'None' /* COMPLETION_TRACKING_NONE */
        WHEN cm.completion = 1 THEN 'Manual self completion' /* COMPLETION_TRACKING_MANUAL */
        WHEN cm.completion = 2 THEN 'Automatic when conditions are met' /* COMPLETION_TRACKING_AUTOMATIC */
    END AS completiontype,
    CASE
       WHEN cmc.completionstate = 0 THEN 'Incomplete' /* COMPLETION_INCOMPLETE */
       WHEN cmc.completionstate = 1 THEN 'Completed' /* COMPLETION_COMPLETE */
       WHEN cmc.completionstate = 2 THEN 'Completed with Pass' /* COMPLETION_COMPLETE_PASS */
       WHEN cmc.completionstate = 3 THEN 'Completed with Fail' /* COMPLETION_COMPLETE_FAIL */
       WHEN cmc.completionstate = 4 THEN 'Completed with Record of Prior Learning' /* COMPLETION_COMPLETE_RPL */
       ELSE 'Unknown'
    END AS completionstate,
    cmc.timemodified
FROM mdl_course_modules_completion cmc
JOIN mdl_user u ON u.id = cmc.userid
JOIN mdl_course_modules cm ON cm.id = cmc.coursemoduleid
JOIN mdl_course c ON c.id = cm.course
JOIN mdl_modules m ON m.id = cm.module
```

Comment: yep, it helped me a lot to explore more about ither database tables